# Combining JavaScript Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to take a JavaScript object that is formatted like:

```
results = {
   names: [
        "id",
        "first_name"
        ],
    values: [
        [
            1234,
            "Fred"
        ],
        [
            4321,
            "Joe"
        ],
        [
            1123,
            "Mary"
        ]
    ]
}
```

and turn into this:

```
    results = {
        [id: 1234, name: "Fred"],
        [id: 4321, name: "Joe"],
        [id: 1123, name: "Mary"]
    }
```

I tried doing something like this, but I can't get the structure correct:

```
var data = []
for (i=0; i < results['values'].length; i++ ){
    var innerData = []
    for (b=0; b < results['names'].length; b++ ){
        innerData.push([name:results['names'][b], value: results['values'][i][b]])
    }
    data.push(innerData)
}
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Problem 1:**

```
results = {
    [id: 1234, name: "Fred"],
    [id: 4321, name: "Joe"],
    [id: 1123, name: "Mary"]
}
```

and

```
var data = []
```

and

```
[name:results['names'][b]…
```

An array `[]` consists a set of values in order.

An object `{}` consists of a set of `key:value` pairs.

You are using the wrong one each time. Use `{}` where you have `[]` and vice versa

---

**Problem 2:**

You say you want objects with `id` and `name` keys, but you are trying to create `name` and `value` keys. Use the property names you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var data = [];
for (i in results['values']){
    var innerData = {}
    var value = results['values'][i];
    for (b in value){
        var key = results['names'][b];
        innerData[key] = value[b]; 
    }
    data.push(innerData);
}
console.log(data);
```